# Interpret negative values of mean decrease accuracy (MDA) in Random Forest

Tags: random-forest, feature-selection, importance

The random forest model has four predictor variables so I used `mtry = 2` (i.e., square root of number of predictor variables) and `ntree = 500` (i.e., default value). I used `randomForest` package for modeling and the results obtained is given below.

Note: I have also tried increasing `ntree` to 1000 and 5000 but still received similar results.

```
            1         2         3         4          5
Q3   8.378854 -1.001002 8.4573160  1.001002 -0.4656459
Q7  -5.174891  2.222748 6.9639438  2.182959 -7.6100442
Q9  -6.145550  2.932870 3.7822210 -0.478020 -3.6996359
Q10 -5.583726  2.878947 0.1527115  6.523781 -4.8365354
    MeanDecreaseAccuracy MeanDecreaseGini
Q3            11.0123237         5.024804
Q7            -0.5622868        10.899521
Q9            -1.9446498        12.623284
Q10           -3.9631560         6.234065
```

Subsequently, I used `randomForestExplainer` package to find top variables based on both Mean Decrease Accuracy (MDA) and Mean Decrease Gini (MDG). The plot below illustrating the results suggests that Q9 and Q7 are both top variables. However, the MDA values for both are negative. So, as a final result which variable should I use, since a negative MDA value for variable suggests that the variable is not predictive enough i.e. not important? On removing the variables with negative values we are left with Q3 only which is not a top variable.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a question.